# GUI to quickly package and distribute a Python Matplotlib project

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib

I have a very basic Matplotlib project with an interactive graph and data filters. I need to put together a GUI for the project and then distribute it within my office to users with no python or command line experience. The look and feel of the GUI is less important, the primary objective is to put this out as soon as possible.

I will need the package I distribute to install the appropriate versions of python and any dependencies, and provide the user with a simple way to launch the application.

The entire office uses Windows 10.

My questions are:

1. What would be the best GUI (Matplotlib backend) given that I have no experience with any of them and I need to deploy this on Windows 10?
   *I am currently researching wxpython and pyqt, any other suggestions? Or a recommendation between the 2?*
2. What would be the best way to deploy this given that the end user will not be able to troubleshoot any problems with dependencies or version conflicts at all?

Comment: Add information to the question by editing the question, not adding a comment.  Also, Bokeh for interactive graphs.  Serve it with a Bokeh server.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thanks I just edited the question. Also thanks for the suggestion I will look into it.